# how do I import a private key corresponding to bech32 address to bitcoin-core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bech32-address, private-key-import

Example address
`bc1q69wqlexdn250purgskahfj9pg2f3ylg82vgy9m`

private key (WIF)
`KyVWvid6fC5WXHrV35ZkxqXgXsYrE9mPxMpusWBFiF771y2AYZrz`

How can I import this into an existing wallet (Bitcoin-qt)?

I tried the other questions about import but that doesn't seem to work anymore (as of 2023).

`importprivatekey` command returns null but that address (or any other address) is nowhere to be seen in QT.

Comment: Do you know if you're trying to import it into a legacy wallet or a newer descriptor based one?

Comment: I used the latest bitcoin-core (downloaded yesterday)

Comment: Ok and did you create a new wallet or import an existing one?
I'm asking all this because wallets are now descriptor based by default, and I think you should use `importdescriptor` instead of `importprivkey` if that's a new wallet. 
That should look something like `wpkh(KyVWvid6fC5WXHrV35ZkxqXgXsYrE9mPxMpusWBFiF771y2AYZrz)`.
I can't help with the gui though, as I haven't used it in ages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be the addresses shown in the Receiving addresses window:
[image: Bitcoin-qt receiving address]

Comment: Wow! the import actually worked. No need for descriptor. It imported 3 addresses, which I assume are, non-segwit, segwit and segwit-bech32. That "receiving address" option is so hidden, that I missed it. I clicked on "Receive" and there were no addresses shown.